# AWS Lambda Node.js execute this.emit after async HTTP request completes

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I am making an API request and would like to ask the user a question with the data returned from the request. I make a call to a function, which executes the request and returns the appropriate response:

```
httpRequest(params).then(function(body) {
  console.log(body);
  this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
});
```

The this.emit function returns an unhandled promise rejection error. How can I wait for the request callback to be executed and then issue the :ask event?

Comment: Can you provide the code for this file in it's entirety? Include all libraries from your code, etc. so we know if you're using the built-in `http` library to make the request and whether you event emission is through web sockets, etc. If `this.emit` returns a promise, what does the following output, `this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, repromptSpeech).catch(console.log)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` inside the promise handler isn't the same as `this` outside of it, so I think the unhandled promise rejection might have stated that `this.emit` isn't a function.

A quick solution would be to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is probably why the code in your own answer works too:

```
// `this` here...
httpRequest(params).then(body => {
  console.log(body);
  this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, repromptSpeech); // ...is the same as `this` here
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('uh-oh!', error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this using the request library:

```
function getEntries() {
  return request.get('https://wezift.com/parent-portal/api/entries.json');
}

getEntries().then(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.emit(':ask', 'hi', 'hi again');
  },
  (error) => {
      console.error('uh-oh! ' + error);
  }
);
```